# How to link my constructor and the buttons that the users can click on?

Tags: c#, wpf

Right now my constructor is empty and does not do what I want.
I have a list of images and when the user clicks on one of the images, a new window should open, displaying the chosen image and its respective description.
Can it be done? What should I write in my constructor? Right now, when the event is triggered by click, no window opens.

This is the code for the list.

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@".\GalleryImages");

foreach (var file in files)
{
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.UriSource = new Uri(file, UriKind.Relative);
    bi.DecodePixelWidth = 20;
    bi.EndInit();

    var button = new KinectTileButton
    {
        Label = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),
        Background = new ImageBrush(bi),
        Tag = file
    };
    var selectionDisplay = new SelectionDisplay(button.Label as string, button.Tag as string);
    this.wrapPanel.Children.Add(button);
}
```

This is the code for the click event.

```
private void KinectTileButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (KinectTileButton)e.Source;
    var image = button.CommandParameter as BitmapImage;
    var selectionDisplay = new SelectionDisplay(button.Label,button.Background); 
    this.kinectRegionGrid.Children.Add(selectionDisplay);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

This is the constructor.

```
public SelectionDisplay(object label, Brush background)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: why don't you use xaml?

Comment: You are creating everything in codebehind

Comment: do you need more details? any solution would be good as long as I can do this.. even with xaml; but what should I do?

Comment: @Blam: The third listing shows what appears to be a constructor.

Comment: Try selectionDisplay.Show()

Answer (score 1):

try adding a handler to your button

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.UriSource = new Uri(file, UriKind.Relative);
bi.DecodePixelWidth = 20;
bi.EndInit();

var button = new KinectTileButton
{
    Label = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),
    Background = new ImageBrush(bi),
    Tag = file
};
**button.Click += KinectTileButtonClick;**
var selectionDisplay = new SelectionDisplay(button.Label as string, button.Tag as string);
this.wrapPanel.Children.Add(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you started with code-behind maybe is less painful for you to understand and use, if i show you how to complete your work.

So here it is:

```
public SelectionDisplay(object label, Brush background)
{
     messageTextBlock.Text= label.ToString();
     Background = background;
}
```

Comment: this is the error I get; if I solve it, I think I will manage to finish my work "The name 'Text' does not exist in the current context 
"

Comment: What type is SelectionDisplay? Window or what?

Comment: http://i61.tinypic.com/xn58hu.png http://i57.tinypic.com/29yiik3.png  it's a type .xaml interface.. I've made a printscreen to make it more clear

Comment: @user3493747 So its a Usercontrol, What do you have in the SectionDisplay.xaml ? a TextBlock to Show the discription?

Comment: right now I don't have anything there. Actually, there is a textblock but it displays this message: "you selected item #". Do I have to create a new textblock? http://i61.tinypic.com/2wq5004.png

Comment: @user3493747 as far as i understood you wanted to display a list of images and when user click that image should be open and show its discription near to that. is that right?

Comment: but I want it to open in a new window.

Comment: the code has no error but it does not do what I want it to do.. When I click the link, the entire app gets an error.. see the image http://i62.tinypic.com/2nkp441.jpg  http://i58.tinypic.com/i2vlol.png

Comment: Before anything to make it be a new Window delete SelectionDisplay and in the solution explorer add a new Window

Comment: @user3493747 you should add a check just below `FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);` you should do something like this
`if(fileInfo.Extension==".jpg"||fileInfo.Extension==".png"|| fileInfo.Extension==".bmp")
{
all the rest
}`

Answer (score 0):

Create a listbox and you can load all you images inside that.
then in the Selection changed event you can right something like this,

// this is a very rough code but should do what you wanted, if am understood currectly

```
 private void lstbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

       Uri uri = new Uri(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(lstbox.SelectedItem.ToString()), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(uri);
        DisplayImg.Source = bmp;
        int index = lstbox.SelectedIndex+1;

        w1 window = new w1();
        window.TXT.Text = "Selected Item Is :" + index;
        window.Show();
    }
 // inside w1.xaml you create something like

<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="Display" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="185" Margin="1,0,-0.4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="293"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TXT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,185,-0.4,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="85" Width="294"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: http://i58.tinypic.com/izxnx5.png http://i58.tinypic.com/2ufequv.png  did i input your code correctly? take a look at the images

Comment: In yourscreenshot its showing errors because you dont have a listbox or name of the listbox is different. and W1 is a window i created to show the image in your case That is Selection Display.

Comment: i strogly suggest you start learning from http://www.wpftutorial.net/ to get a better idea.

Comment: what should I write instead of listbox? I can't figure out the name of my listbox..

Comment: you can come in the chat

Comment: what chat? how do i enter it?

Comment: forget it you dont have reputation to do that. i dont see any way

Comment: then let's try and solve the errors here.. I've attached another image with the new errors http://i58.tinypic.com/29c56qa.png

Comment: email:d.crysty23@yahoo.com